# How to use Unity in order to implement a simple component publishing engine

Tags: .net, unity-container, ioc-container

In our project we have implemented a simple facility to let one party publish dynamic components and yet others - to consume them. I would like to phase out our in-house implementation and take something ready off the shelf. Since our UI guys already use Caliburn+Prism+Unity, I decided to go with Unity (having two different IoC container implementations seems like a strange thing to do).

For the sake of the question, here are the players:

1. Entity types (`A`, `B`)
2. Entity factories (`FactoryA`, `FactoryB`)
3. Entity manager (`Manager`)
4. Client

As of now, `Manager` has `RegisterFactory(IFactory)` API, which is the only way to register new entity types - one has to call it passing the new entity factory instance.

However, explicit calls to this method by Client are rare, because the `Manager` runs our in-house engine, which examines all the assemblies in a certain folder and loads those, which declare certain assembly level attribute. The attribute specifies the type of particular entity factory, so that the engine can instantiate it (using `Activator.CreateInstance`) and invoke the `RegisterFactory` API.

In addition, the engine monitors the folder and knows to load new assemblies on the fly.

For instance, if C is a new entity type implemented in an assembly Foo.dll, then the assembly should have an assebly level attribute like so:

```
[assembly: PublishEntity(typeof(FactoryC))]
```

Then placing Foo.dll in that special folder causes the engine to:

1. examine it and find there the relevant assembly level attribute instance
2. Create a new `FactoryC` instance using reflection
3. Invoke `Manager.RegisterFactory`, passing the `FactoryC` instance as the argument.

The point is that I wish to use Unity to achieve the same functionality.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Both Manager and Factory types are needed. What I am interested to eliminate is the ad-hoc registration facility - the attribute, the RegisterFactory method and the engine that scans the folder and loads the relevant assemblies. Now I realize that Unity may not be enough. I am interested to know about the complimentary solutions which will satisfy our needs. I just wish to use something well known and tested, preferably something aspiring to be standard.

Answer (score 0):

Unity requires a type config, either in the app config or built at runtime. Your current engine adds value by doing assembly probing. Unity just doesn't do that.

The only purpose I see Unity serving is replacing your Manager and possibly your Factory classes by allowing Client to resolve Entities (and Factories?) using Unity. You could keep allowing your engine to hot-configure Unity with assemblies that it finds.